# How does a packet flow in the network?

Tags: networking, packet, packet-sniffers

I wanted to know how does a packet actually flow in the network .. For example suppose there are two computers A and B behind a router. Packet for A arrives at the router. Is this packet sent to both A and B and then the packets IP is validated with the computers IP to know the final destination? The reason why i asked this question is because i didn't understand how a packet sniffer works internally

Comment: The packet isn't sent to either A or B. It is put into the router's inside network if it is for an address inside that network. A or B as appropriate sees the packet as being for itself and passes it up the stack, or alternatively sees that it's for someone else and ignores it.

Comment: @EJP so suppose the packet wasn't for B .. How can i still see take the packet for analyzing like a sniffer does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the hosts in IPv4 environment are assigned unique logical IP addresses. When a host wants to send some data to another host on the network, it needs the physical (MAC) address of the destination host. To get the MAC address, the host broadcasts ARP message and asks to give the MAC address whoever is the owner of destination IP address. All the host on that segment receives ARP packet but only the host which has its IP matching with the one in ARP message, replies with its MAC address. Once the sender receives the MAC address of receiving station, data is sent on the physical media.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the network.  If A and B are both connected to the router with a shared-medium network such as coaxial Ethernet, then the router will put the packet on the wire, and both A and B will read the packet from the wire, but B will ignore it as it is not addressed to B.  If on the other hand you're using a switched network with a separate wire for A and for B, the router will hand the packet to the switch, which will copy it just to the wire for A, unless B has negotiated promiscuous monitoring with the switch, in which case the switch will also send it to B

Comment: So is this the reason why packet sniffing is actually possible? Instead of B ignoring the packet it takes it no matter what?

Comment: If B sees the packet (i'ts on the wire or on the air for wifi), B needs to decode it and see who it is for, before it can throw it away if it's not for B

Answer (score 0):

Condition -1 PC1 -192.168.1.5 PC2 192.168.1.3
Condition -2 PC1 192.168.1.5 PC2 192.168.2.3

Condition-1

When PC 1 one want o send packet to PC 2 it will first check for Source and Destination MAC as all Communication happens at Layer 2 or Data Link layer happens at MAC . Source MAC address will be of PC 1 and destination MAC address will be of of PC 2 which is unknown in this situation . PC will generate ARP to find the MAC address of PC 2 as both Host and Destination are on same network that is 192.168.1.1 once the ARP request Fetch the MAC address of PC Switch will look in CAM table to which port he need to forward the frame. if there is no entry in CAM table , Switch will send broadcast to find out on which port PC 2 is connected and forward the frame to PC 2

Condition 2

When PC see source IP and Destination IP address are not of same sub net it know the packet need to forwarded to default gateway . It will start looking for MAC address of default gateway which should be available , in case MAC address for Default gateway is not available then it will generate ARP request find the Default gateway MAC address and send it to default gateway .

at default gateway new frame is created Source Ip 192.168.1.5 Destination IP  192.168.2.5 Source MAC of PC 1 and Destination MAC of Default gateway .

at router will check what interface 192.168.2.1 is connected and will route the Packet to particular interface .

now the destination is on same sub net it will look for the MAC address of 192.168.2.3 and forward the frame to PC 2

Please note Source IP and Destination IP never changes in packet flow .

Source and Destination MAC changes